# Vue.js dynamic component render "Failed to resolve directive"

Tags: vue.js

Currently I have solved things in an other way, but I am still curious why this is not working.

I'm trying to render a transition with a template with 2 directives, but it seems it tries to resolve the attrs/props from an other scope, but I can't see why at this point. Perhaps I just made a stupid mistake.

This gives me the error:
"[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve directive: ..." for both bind and text

```
<script>
    import Step from './Step';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                pointer: 0,
                steps: [],
            }
        },

        render(createElement) {
            this.steps = this.$slots.default
                .filter(vnode => vnode.tag && vnode.tag.indexOf(Step.name) > -1);

            this.pointer = this.steps[0].key;

            return createElement('div',
                {},
                [
                    createElement('transition',
                        {},
                        [
                            createElement('template', {
                                directives: [
                                    {name: 'bind', arg: 'key', value: 'pointer'},
                                    {name: 'text', value: 'step'},
                                ],
                            })
                        ]
                    )
                ]);
        },

        computed: {
            step() {
                return _.find(this.steps, step => step.key === this.pointer);
            }
        },

        methods: {
            next() {
                ++this.pointer;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: more likely is `createElement('transition',
                        {},
                        [
                            createElement('template', {
                                props: {'key':'pointer'},
                                domProps: {
    innerHTML: 'step'
  },
                            })
                        ]
                    )`

Comment: Doesn't that make the key attribute just a static text 'pointer' instead of listning to the key property? Same for the 'step' computed attribute.